# Shopping cart item list dropdown arrow

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
.bagitem-main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 10px;
  max-width: 1260px;
  direction: rtl;
  background-color: green;
}

.bagitem-box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 290px;
  direction: ltr;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  pointer-events: auto;
  display: block;
  top: 4px;
  left: 0;
}

.bagitem-arrow {
  opacity: 1.0;
  position: absolute;
  background: #ffffff;
  margin-left: 19px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.bagitem-arrow::after,
.bagitem-arrow::before {
  opacity: 1.0;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.bagitem-arrow::after {
  opacity: 1.0;
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
  border-width: 10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.bagitem-arrow::before {
  opacity: 1.0;
  border-color: rgba(214, 214, 214, 0);
  border-bottom-color: #d6d6d6;
  border-width: 11px;
  margin-left: -11px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bagitem-arrow" id="bagitem-arrow"></div>
<div class="bagitem-main">
  <div class="bagitem-box">
    <p>hi hi hi hi h i ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi hihi h ih ih i hi hi hi </p>
    <p>hi hi hi hi h i ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi hihi h ih ih i hi hi hi </p>
    <p>hi hi hi hi h i ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi hihi h ih ih i hi hi hi </p>
    <p>hi hi hi hi h i ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi hihi h ih ih i hi hi hi </p>
    <p>hi hi hi hi h i ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi hihi h ih ih i hi hi hi </p>
    <p>hi hi hi hi h i ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi hihi h ih ih i hi hi hi </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm developing a shopping cart html website. and in that website, I need onclick cart item dropdown. in that dropdown I need this arrow and a div **separate**. I'm trying to remove a grey line showing between arrow and div but don't know how to do it.

[image]

Comment: you mean you dont need the grey line only under the arrow part?

Comment: yes like that i want

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have added `border-color` to grey before and after `bagitem-arrow`. If you do not want the grey `border`, then add `z-index:1` to your `bagitem-arrow` class. Try the snippet below:

```css
.bagitem-main {
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative;
 min-width: 10px;
 max-width: 1260px;
 direction: rtl;
 background-color: green;
}

.bagitem-box {
 position: absolute;
 width: 290px;
 direction: ltr;
 background-color: white;
 border-radius: 2px;
 border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
 pointer-events: auto;
 display: block;
    top: 4px;
    left: 0;
}

.bagitem-arrow {
 opacity: 1.0;
 position: absolute;
 background: #ffffff;
 margin-left: 19px;
 margin-top: 5px;
    z-index: 1; /* Add z-index to your arrow */
}

.bagitem-arrow::after, .bagitem-arrow::before {
 opacity: 1.0;
 bottom: 100%;
 left: 50%;     
 border: solid transparent;
 content: " ";
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 position: absolute;
 pointer-events: none;
}

.bagitem-arrow::after {
 opacity: 1.0;
 border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
 border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
 border-width: 10px;
 margin-left: -10px;
}

.bagitem-arrow::before {
 opacity: 1.0;
 border-color: rgba(214, 214, 214, 0);
 border-bottom-color: #d6d6d6;
 border-width: 11px;
 margin-left: -11px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bagitem-arrow" id="bagitem-arrow"></div>
<div class="bagitem-main">           
    <div class="bagitem-box">            
        <p>hi hi hi hi h i ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi hihi h ih ih i hi hi hi </p>
        <p>hi hi hi hi h i ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi hihi h ih ih i hi hi hi </p>
        <p>hi hi hi hi h i ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi hihi h ih ih i hi hi hi </p>
        <p>hi hi hi hi h i ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi hihi h ih ih i hi hi hi </p>
        <p>hi hi hi hi h i ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi hihi h ih ih i hi hi hi </p>
        <p>hi hi hi hi h i ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi hihi h ih ih i hi hi hi </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS CODE**
add  `z-index:1;` on the class  `.bagitem-arrow::after`

```css
 .bagitem-main {
     
     margin: 0 auto;
     position: relative;
     min-width: 10px;
     max-width: 1260px;
     direction: rtl;
     background-color: green;
    }




    .bagitem-box {
     
  
     position: absolute;
     width: 290px;
     direction: ltr;
     background-color: white;
     border-radius: 2px;
     border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
     pointer-events: auto;
     display: block;
        top: 4px;
        left: 0;
     
    }

    .bagitem-arrow {
     opacity: 1.0;
     position: absolute;
     background: #ffffff;
     margin-left: 19px;
     margin-top: 5px;
     
    }
    .bagitem-arrow::after, .bagitem-arrow::before {
     opacity: 1.0;
      bottom: 100%;
     left: 50%;
        border: solid transparent;
     content: " ";
     height: 0;
     width: 0;
     position: absolute;
     pointer-events: none;
    }

    .bagitem-arrow::after {
     opacity: 1.0;
     border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
     border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
     border-width: 10px;
     margin-left: -10px;
        z-index:1;
    }
    .bagitem-arrow::before {
     opacity: 1.0;
     border-color: rgba(214, 214, 214, 0);
     border-bottom-color: #d6d6d6;
     border-width: 11px;
     margin-left: -11px;
    }
```

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `z-index: 1;` which gets the arrow to the front. Add `filter: drop-shadow(rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0px 0px 0px);` to get border for the arrow. And change the `border-bottom-color: #ffffff;` to match the background. [Check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yxtzmhp2/1/)

```css
.bagitem-main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 10px;
  max-width: 1260px;
  direction: rtl;
  background-color: green;
}

.bagitem-box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 290px;
  direction: ltr;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  pointer-events: auto;
  display: block;
  top: 4px;
  left: 0;
}

.bagitem-arrow {
  opacity: 1.0;
  position: absolute;
  background: #ffffff;
  margin-left: 19px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.bagitem-arrow::after,
.bagitem-arrow::before {
  opacity: 1.0;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.bagitem-arrow::after {
  opacity: 1.0;
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
  border-width: 10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.bagitem-arrow::before {
  opacity: 1.0;
  border-color: rgba(214, 214, 214, 0);
  border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
  border-width: 11px;
  margin-left: -11px;
  z-index: 1;
  filter: drop-shadow(rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0px 0px 0px);
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0px 0px 0px);
}
```

```html
<div class="bagitem-arrow" id="bagitem-arrow"></div>
<div class="bagitem-main">
  <div class="bagitem-box">
    <p>hi hi hi hi h i ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi hihi h ih ih i hi hi hi </p>
    <p>hi hi hi hi h i ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi hihi h ih ih i hi hi hi </p>
    <p>hi hi hi hi h i ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi hihi h ih ih i hi hi hi </p>
    <p>hi hi hi hi h i ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi hihi h ih ih i hi hi hi </p>
    <p>hi hi hi hi h i ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi hihi h ih ih i hi hi hi </p>
    <p>hi hi hi hi h i ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi hihi h ih ih i hi hi hi </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

there's a class missing from the code snippet:
.bagitem-box
remove the border property and you're good.